# Twitter bootstrap - navigation bar absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the latest version of Twitter Bootstrap and I want to absolutely position the navigation bar on top of the page.

Here's how the code looks like :

```
<div class="navbar navbar-transparent navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  ......
<section id="slider">
... here is the markup for a slider...
```

If I use `navbar-static-top` it will not position on top of the slider section and I have to add a negative top margin for the slider section in order to make the navigation bar to stay on top of the slider section like this:

```
#slider { 
position:relative;
top:-90px;
}
```

Here's also a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/lemiyuxipi/1/) to see exactly what I'm talking about;
Is there a more correct, semantic way to do this ? I don't want to use fixed positioning.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you have an image?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct, you want the navbar to be displayed above the slider. Am I correct?

If so, why not simply give the `.navbar` `position:absolute;`? If there are any overlaying issues, you can use `z-index` to control them.

Here is a [**working example**](http://jsbin.com/lirunawove/1/edit?html,css,js,output).

Comment: Just as a sidenote: you can also use position:fixed; to keep it at the top if you scroll down.

Comment: @docodemore Well the OP stated he doesn't want to use `position: fixed`, thats why I recommended this instead..

Comment: I get it :) It's the proper suggestion.  I was just adding a sidenote about position fixed not meaning to critique your answer.  It's a good answer given the question.

Comment: I was thinking to use absolute positioning too but as you see in your example it moves to the left so I kind of have to use some css styles in order to center it and also I have to take care of the responsiveness.